# Change the path for Qt libraries

Tags: c++, qt, path, dependencies

I am building an application using Qt 5.3 and I want to run this application on a machine that doesn't have Qt libraries installed on it. I know I must place the Qt required DLLs in the executable's folder to avoid dependency crashes, since I am linking to them on runtime (I am using the default Qt building settings). I don't want to change the environment variables of the client's machine (I don't want to change the "path" variable), but I want to place Qt libraries inside a sub-directory of my application. 
For example:

If my application directory is `C:\myApp\`, I want to place my Qt DLLs (QtCore, QtNetwork, etc) in `C:\myApp\QtLibs`.
Is there a way to make it?

Comment: Can you not specify the location of the libraries being used inside the project file?

Comment: They are on the default Qt directory.

Comment: In my machine it is "C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\bin"

Comment: The machine in which the application will be run doesn't have Qt libraries on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no easy ways of doing that on Windows. Windows has [predefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx) search paths. An ugly but simple solution would be to use a .bat/.cmd script or another executable to run the Qt application with altered `PATH` environment variable.

There is another hacky way to load all libraries manually with [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [LoadLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then library search paths could be adjusted with [SetDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem! Just use code like this:

```
#ifndef _DEBUG
    foreach (const QString path, app.libraryPaths())
        app.removeLibraryPath(path);
    app.setLibraryPaths(QStringList() << app.applicationDirPath() 
                                      << (QString("%1/Plugins").arg(app.applicationDirPath())));
#else
    app.setLibraryPaths(app.libraryPaths() << QString("%1/Plugins").arg(app.applicationDirPath()));
#endif
```

Place code in main() function

Comment: I inserted your code, but the application is still looking for the required libraries in its own folder.

Comment: You must change ("%1/Plugins") to the name of your directory(QtLibs etc.), It was just example from my old application. Good luck!

Comment: And you can delete removing pathes for release version(foreach cycle), this was necessary in older Qt versions.

Comment: This solution will only work for libraries loaded after the application object, the code of which exists inside the QtCoreX library. At the very least, QtCoreX must exist in the same directory as the application executable.